# Microsoft Word Macro to edit and replace what is inside a variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to do the following in a macro

```
If sFolderName contains ".pdf"
// Do Something
Else // Do Something
End If
```

but I do not know how to find out if .pdf is inside the variable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, you can use the `InStr` function to search for the position of one string inside another string.

The syntax of the function is: InStr([start,]string1,string2[,compare])

In your scenario, `string1` will be `sFolderName` and `string2` would be `".pdf"`. In other words, you are searching for the position in sFolderName where the text ".pdf" begins.

If `string2` is found within `string1`, then `InStr` returns the position at which match is found.

```
If InStr(sFolderName, ".pdf") > 0 Then
   // do something
Else
   // do something else
End If
```

For more information, please consult this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031%28VS.60%29.aspx).